# Adding/removing records in a child relationship list

Tags: apex, childrelationship

I am passing a list of SObjects with child relationships to a Lightning Web Component.  If I query and pass my query results back to my LWC component directly, this works.

In Apex:

```java
return [
    SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, LastName FROM Contacts)
    FROM Account
];
```

In LWC, I get a nice, nested JavaScript object:

```js
[
  {
    Id: "0012D00000PDWKAQA5", 
    Contacts: {
      Id: '0032D00000Ni9yZQAR',
      LastName: 'Test' 
    } 
  },
  ...
]
```

Now I have a requirement that involves adding and removing child records before returning the response to my LWC component.  But I'm noticing some weird behavior when I try to manipulate the child relationship, which I had assumed was just a `List` type.  When I use `add()`, nothing is added.  When I use `remove()`, nothing is removed.  And yet, no exception is thrown.

For example, you can run this in Execute Anonymous:

```java
Account acc = [
    SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, LastName FROM Contacts)
    FROM Account
    WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact)
    LIMIT 1
];
Integer contactNum = acc.Contacts.size();
acc.Contacts.add(new Contact(LastName = 'Test'));
// THIS FAILS
System.assertEquals(contactNum + 1, acc.Contacts.size());
```

...or...

```java
...
acc.Contacts.remove(0);
// THIS FAILS TOO
System.assertEquals(contactNum - 1, acc.Contacts.size());
```

I tried working around this by setting `acc.Contacts` directly, e.g. `acc.Contacts = new List<Contact>();`.  This returns an exception: "`Field is not writeable: Account.Contacts`"

Any help?

Comment: One of the approaches could be to do a deserialization (f.e. serialize to string, then deserialize to map<String, Object>, call put on it with "Contacts" as field name, and serialize it back". Personally I would not go with route, but use custom wrapper class to make it more flexible and controllable

Comment: These are OK workarounds as workarounds go.  It's a layer of complexity I would generally hope to avoid, but that might not be possible in this case.  And I'm still sort of looking for some deeper insight into what `acc.Contacts` is, if not a `List`, and why `add()` and `remove()` fail silently on whatever it is.

Comment: `acc.Contacts` is definitely a `List` (verified using `acc.Contacts instanceOf List<Contact>` in your sample code), but looks like apex is treating it as immutable. By immutable, I mean the contacts list itself is read-only (or restricted for add/ remove) but fields within the retrieved contact records are writeable. I guess SF would have some strong reasons to do this, but couldn't find any SF documentation that explains about this.